# Can I call `glDrawArrays` multiple times while updating the same `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, opengl-3

In a single frame, is it "allowed" to update the same `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` continuously and keep calling `glDrawArrays` after each update?

I know this is probably not the best and not the most recommended way to do it, but my question is: Can I do this and expect to get the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` updated before every call to `glDrawArrays` ?

Code example would look like this:

```
// setup a single buffer and bind it
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

while (!renderStack.empty())
{
    SomeObjectClass * my_object = renderStack.back();
    renderStack.pop_back();

    // calculate the current buffer size for data to be drawn in this iteration
    SomeDataArrays * subArrays = my_object->arrayData();
    unsigned int totalBufferSize = subArrays->bufferSize();
    unsigned int vertCount = my_object->vertexCount();

    // initialise the buffer to the desired size and content
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalBufferSize, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    // actually transfer some data to the GPU through glBufferSubData
    for (int j = 0; j < subArrays->size(); ++j)
    {
        unsigned int subBufferOffset = subArrays->get(j)->bufferOffset();
        unsigned int subBufferSize = subArrays->get(j)->bufferSize();
        void * subBufferData = subArrays->get(j)->bufferData();

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, subBufferOffset, subBufferSize, subBufferData);

        unsigned int subAttributeLocation = subArrays->get(j)->attributeLocation();

        // set some vertex attribute pointers
        glVertexAttribPointer(subAttributeLocation, ...);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(subAttributeLocation, ...);
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (GLsizei)vertCount);
}
```

You may ask - why would I want to do that and not just preload everything onto the GPU at once ... well, obvious answer, because I can't do that when there is too much data that can't fit into a single buffer.

**My problem** is, that I can only see the result of one of the `glDrawArrays` calls (I believe the first one) or in other words, it appears as if the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not updated before each `glDrawArrays` call, which brings me back to my question, if this is even possible.

*I am using an OpenGL 3.2 CoreProfile (under OS X) and link with GLEW for OpenGL setup as well as Qt 5 for setting up the window creation.*

Comment: have you tried glBufferSubData

Comment: yes, I am actually using `glBufferSubData` to copy in separate parts of the buffer, but I still have to call `glBufferData` to resize it ... either way - is there a difference which one I call in regards to my question ?

Comment: @Chris: your approach is valid. The GL will do all the implicit synchronizations necessary for this to work for you. Actually, since calling `glBufferData()` allocates a new storage for the buffer object, a sensible implementation could get away without any further synchonizations, so the approach should even not be as bad as you might think (but you can't rely on that either). I don't know what goes wrong in your case, but I can definitively confirm that buffer update itself is not the issue.

Comment: @derhass thanks for the confirmation, as you can imagine this is a bit of a pain to debug with datasets containing millions of points ... I extended my example to show that I am also using `glBufferSubData` to transfer parts of the buffer, but I assume this won't make any difference either, right ?

Comment: @Chris: The `BufferSubData` part is OK (assuiming you got your sizes and offsets right). However, the code does not make sense in that you set the `VertexAttribPointer` in the inner loop. Only the last one will be effective, when you finally call `DrawArrays`.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out that I had calculated a wrong buffer offset for one of the buffers, which causes my issues. I am calling `glVertexAttribPointer` in the inner loop, because I reference a different attribute location every time, so all of them are active - I'll extend that in the example to make it more obvious.

Comment: Does changing to GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW make a difference?  It helped me with a similar issue on Windows (driver related).

Comment: @Robinson I'll keep that in mind, but for now `GL_STREAM_DRAW` did work for me (testing on Nvidia card) as long as I calculate the right buffer offsets ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is legal OpenGL code. It is in no way something that anyone should ever actually do. But it is legal. Indeed, it makes even less sense in your case, because you're calling `glVertexAttribPointer` for every object.

If you can't fit all your vertex data into memory, or need to generate it on the GPU, then you should stream the data with proper [buffer streaming techniques](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).